# Router unable to stream files

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, streaming

I am having some problems with my home network. I have a server and client, with the server having a lot of movies on it, and it is supposed to stream to the client though a normal network share.

This has worked perfectly for years, but I just moved and got a new router,  and since then I have not been able to stream movies without it having to stop and buffer every two minutes.

- The server is connected via an Ethernet cable, and the client is connected though wireless, with full signal
- The server and client are both Windows 2008 R2 Server
- My router is a Netgear CDG24G

What can I do to make the streaming work again, and what is wrong with my router?

Comment: The CDG25G supports 54Mbps network speeds, so will only be suitable for standard definition video.  What definition videos are you playing?

Comment: 720p movies, more chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the bitrate of the video, a high-definition movie approaches or even exceeds the amount of bandwidth available on an 802.11g wifi connection.

Sometimes you will get away with it.  An 802.11n access point along with an 802.11n wifi card in the client will solve this problem.